# Can Narsie be defeated?

Tags: space-station-13

Can Narsie, the big bad monster that Cultists can summon given enough members, be destroyed with enough firepower or force (or perhaps a singularity)?  Or is he completely unstoppable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that he is completely unstoppable, as far as I can tell he is just a way for the cultists to win the round and the little cut-scene that shows Narsie rising is just fluff.

Comment: It's not so much a cut-scene as it is the character actually appearing, but I'll take that as word that he cannot be beaten.